# Unable to send/upload image with axios through formdata in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, multipartform-data

I've tried following ways but it just does not work while image is being uploaded through postman. What is my mistake?

```
  export const updateProfile = data => dispatch => {
  const {name, dateOfBirth, gender, customerId, phone, image} = data;
  var bodyFormData = new FormData();    
  bodyFormData.append('image', image);
  bodyFormData.append('name', name);
  bodyFormData.append('dateOfBirth', dateOfBirth);
  bodyFormData.append('gender', gender);
  bodyFormData.append('customerId', customerId);
  bodyFormData.append('phone', phone);
  // bodyFormData.append('file', {
  //   uri: image,
  //   type: 'image/png',
  //   name: 'abc.png',
  // });

  axios({
    url: `${baseUrl}/update-customer`,
    method: 'POST',
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log('updateProfile res', response.data);
```

Comment: could you share what it returns from backend?

Comment: {"data": {"_id": "*****",  "created_at": "2022-09-06T10", "dateOfBirth": "2020-12-05", "gender": "Female", "name": "Hsj", "phone": "639", "role": "customer", "updated_at": "2022-09-06T10"}, "message": "Customer updated successfully", "status": 200}

Comment: Are you sure `image` is a valid file?

Comment: yes i am sure.. i'm using a png file

Comment: what version of axios are you using ?

Comment: installed latest

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `type` and `name` with image as well before uploading.

Uncomment your commented code

```
bodyFormData.append('file', {
   uri: image,
   type: 'multipart/form-data',
   name: 'abc.png',
});
```

Try once

Comment: commented bcuz this does not works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Try using  `'type': 'multipart/form-data'`